# Alignment in Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android

Is alignment working in HTML.fromHtml() in a TextView?

I tried

```
<div align="center"><p>Test</p></div>
```

and some variaties of this, including putting the alignment tabs without parenthesis to the paragraph tag, but none worked. The text is always left.

Thanks for any help!

Yours.

Answer (score 15):

Alignment is not supported in HTML text in TextView.

Comment: What a nice site this is with all these helpful people and quick answers! However, the follow-up is obvious: What HTML is supported?

Comment: THe supported tags are: p, div, em, b, strong, cite, dfn, i, big, small, font, blockquote, tt, a, u, sup, sub, h1 to h6 and img. Note that you can also provide your own TagHandler by calling fromHtml(String, ImageGetter, TagHandler). This lets you add support for any tag you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would like a centered alignment. This seems to be impossible in the text view at all, so a handler would not help.

Comment: You can set the text alignment using android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: how do you set text alignment then? for example right-to-left ? i know it's available for android 4.3 in some way, but what about older versions?

Answer (score 12):

To set alignment in textview first set textview width to match_parent and then use text-align option in your HTML tag. something like this:

`<div style="text-align: center">this text should be in center of view</div>`

Update:
This solution just work in android 7 and above :|

Comment: Verified works on Android 11. BTW, you can monkeypatch HTML you don't control with something like this: `val fixHtml = html.replace("<center>","<div style=\"text-align: center\">").replace("</center>","</div>")`

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible to use alignment using a webview instead of a TextView, and loading the html from a file placed in assets:

```
public class ViewWeb extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.webview);

       webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set alignment in HTML text but you can use a [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) instead. It's verbose but it gets the job done.

E.g.

```
private Spanned getFormattedLabelText(String text, String subText) {
    String fullText = String.format("%s\n%s", text, subText);

    int fullTextLength = fullText.length();
    int titleEnd = text.length();

    SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder(fullText);

    // Center align the text
    AlignmentSpan alignmentSpan = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    s.setSpan(alignmentSpan, 0, fullTextLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Make the title bold
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, titleEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //bold

    // Make the subtext small
    int smallTextSize = DisplayUtil.getPixels(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
    s.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(smallTextSize), titleEnd + 1, fullTextLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //bold

    return s;
}
```

Then set the TextView text as usual:

```
myTextView.setText(getFormattedLabelText("Title", "Subtitle"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For API 24 and below, add a `gravity` attribute to the `TextView` layout element

```
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

For API 24 and above, can use a `style` within the HTML.

```java
  String centeredHtml = "<div style=\"text-align: center\">" + myFormattedHtml + "</div>";
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(centeredHtml));
```

But `gravity` is also supported up to at least API 26.

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to align text in center with color red then one may use code below.

```
String centerNRed = "<div style='text-align:center' ><span style='color:red' >Hello World Its me.....</span></div>";
txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(centerNRed));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe is more easy use the property Gravity in a TextView for center the text...