# How could I easily display a custom text without too many TextViews

Tags: android, textview

For example, doing centered text and underlined etc... could be possible with a lot of textviews but is there a way not to use that much? Or maybe a way to type html and have the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `HTML` tag?

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Underlined</u>"));
```

Comment: Can I use complex HTML? If not, what are the limitations?

Comment: The supported tags are: p, div, em, b, strong, cite, dfn, i, big, small, font, blockquote, tt, a, u, sup, sub, h1 to h6 and img. Note that you can also provide your own TagHandler by calling fromHtml(String, ImageGetter, TagHandler). This lets you add support for any tag you want. source [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874999/alignment-in-html-fromhtml]