# Text is not in center in my view using fromHtml()

Tags: android, html, xml, android-layout, fromhtml

I am setting a textview with **fromHtml()**, and my TextView is not set in center. In below image you can **show space** bigger **below** of *paragraf* text, I don't know how to resolve this issue, other **normal** text it's fine but **fromHtml** its leave **some space** not in the center.

Setting textview like this

```
txtOffer.text = Html.fromHtml(<h1>Hello i am using your app</h1>, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

This is xml code

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_offer"
                style="@style/txt_heavy_oblique"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp" 
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12" />

    </LinearLayout>

  <style name="txt_heavy_oblique" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_14</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AvenirHeavyOblique</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874999/alignment-in-html-fromhtml[use this link may be help you][1]

Comment: [Use this link may be help from you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874999/alignment-in-html-fromhtml)

Comment: I checked but not proper

Answer (score 0):

don't use  tag in html it will create margins problem.
If you need only different size, you can use simple  or  and you can use it more times for one char.
Example: "classic text is ok, but bigger is  better".

Answer (score 0):

Many research I found this lib, and its very useful and solve my problem

> https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Thanks to @Avinash Ajay Pandey for your support. :)